# Build a PHP API that doesn't require constant requests

Tags: javascript, php

I am working to build an IP in PHP. I'm using Fetch method in JavaScript to get the response. When something changes on server, it need to send a response to JS. To do this I was using `setInterval()` and repeat each second. These are too much requests. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Websockets is the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a websocket server easily which emits the client to update the data (also you can emit the updated data as well).

As far as I know react.js does the same thing in development mode, you should check it out, probably it will help a lot.

Comment: What's the best way to learn websockets in php. I read articels and watch youtube videos but i understand nothing

Comment: PHP is not for WS connections. You should use a nodejs api for that. But if you want PHP you should check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).